# How to assign a function with members to a variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, functor

Here's what I’m trying to do:

```
interface FunctionWithState {
    (): void;
    state: number;
}

var inc: FunctionWithState = {
    state: 0,
    apply: () => this.state++; // wrong syntax
};
```

Basically, I want the function to maintain some state accessible from outside. How can I assign a variable of the type `FunctionWithState`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that specific line, you have a wrong semi colon. Fix :

```
interface FunctionWithState {
    state: number;
}

var inc: FunctionWithState = {
    state: 0,
    apply: () => this.state++ // right syntax
};
```

However I suspect you are using `()=>` wrong. You want it to refer to inc and not the global variable `this` which is `window` in this case.

Perhaps you mean to use a class :

```
interface FunctionWithState {
    state: number;
}

class Inc implements FunctionWithState {
    state =  0;

    apply = () => this.state++;
};

var inc = new Inc();
inc.apply();
```

If you really want to be plain javascripty about it you can do the following. But then you cannot call the apply function (as it does not exist on `FunctionWithState`):

```
interface FunctionWithState {
    (): void;
    state: number;
}

var tmp: any = function() { }
tmp.state = 0;
tmp.apply = function() { return this.state++; };
var inc: FunctionWithState = tmp;
```

Comment: OK, but I'd like to use `inc` as a function like so: `inc()`. Can I do that?

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way for me to assign an object to a variable of type `FunctionWithState` as defined in my question?